# Anagram with condition on last letter

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many ways can "computer" be arranged with a vowel as last alphabet?
Isn't it $7! \times 3 $? since there are 3 vowels. $3$ (e,o,u) $ \times 7!$(number of arrangement without one of vowel). Shouldn't it be right?

Comment: Your argument is correct.

Comment: That is correct.  As per usual, you place the elements with the most restriction first (in this case, a vowel in the last slot), and then proceed to place the rest.  A friendly reminder that by visiting this page [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can read a primer on how to format mathematics on the site to make it more easily readable.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is correct.

Approach via multiplication principle.

- Pick the vowel to occupy the last space in the word (three choices)
- Pick the letter to occupy the first space of the word (7 remaining choices)
- Pick the letter to occupy the second space of the word (6 remaining choices)

  $\vdots$
- Pick the letter to occupy the second to last space in the word (1 remaining choice)

For a total of $3\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdots 1 = 3\cdot 7!$ number of different such arrangements.

---

Note that the letters of "computer" are all different - if some letters of the inital word were the same, we would need to divide by the number of identical arrangements of those letters.